# Passing query parameters in Pandas

Tags: sql-server-2005, pandas

Trying to write a simple pandas script which executes a query from SQL Server with WHERE clause.  However, the query doesnt return any values. Possibly because the parameter is not passed? I thought we could pass the key-value pairs as below. Can you please point out what i am doing wrong here?

Posting just the query and relevant pieces. All the libraries have been imported as needed.

```
  curr_sales_month = '2015-08-01'
  sql_query = """SELECT sale_month,region,oem,nameplate,Model,Segment,Sales  FROM [MONTHLY_SALES] WHERE Sale_Month = %(salesmonth)s"""
    print ("Executed SQL Extract", sql_query)

    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,conn,params={"salesmonth":curr_sales_month})
```

The program returned with:
       Closed Connection - Fetched 0 rows for Report

```
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Which driver are you using? The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Further, if you just execute the full query (with the value for curr_sales_month already filled in), does it then return the correct result?

Comment: Here is a list of the different formats: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle, and not all DBAPI2 drivers support all formats.

Comment: You mention SQL server but the style of variable replacement %(salesmonth)s was quite unfamiliar to me for SQL server. In the docs i believe it relates to using the library psycopg2 which would be for Postgres

Answer (score 4):

Further to my comment. Here is an example that uses pyodbc to communicate to sql server and demonstrates passing a variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',50)
pd.set_option('display.width',5000)

conn_str = r"DRIVER={0};SERVER={1};DATABASE={2};UID={3};PWD={4}".format("SQL Server",'.','master','user','pwd')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = ?"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql = sql_statement, con = cnxn, params = [2])
cnxn.close()
print df.iloc[:,0:2].head()
```

which produces:

```
     name  database_id 
0  tempdb            2
```

And if you wish to pass multiple parameters:

```
sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > ? and database_id < ?"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql = sql_statement, con = cnxn, params = [2,5])
cnxn.close()
print df.iloc[:,0:2].head()
```

which produces:

```
    name  database_id
0  model            3
1   msdb            4
```

---

my preferred way with dynamic inline sql statements

```
create_date = '2015-01-01'
name = 'mod'

sql_statement_template = r"""SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > {0} AND database_id < {1} AND create_date > '{2}' AND name LIKE '{3}%'"""
sql_statement = sql_statement_template.format('2','5',create_date,name)
print sql_statement
```

yields

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 2 AND database_id < 5 AND create_date > '2015-01-01' AND name LIKE 'mod%'
```

A further benefit if you do print this out, is you can copy and paste the sql commnand to management studio (or equivalent) and test your sql syntax easily.

and result should be:

```
    name  database_id
0  model            3
```

So this example demonstrates handling: date,string and int datatypes. 
Including a LIKE with wildcard %

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and apologies for leaving the details. I am using pymssql driver.  Thanks for the example too - I was reading somewhere that passing in string parameters is a bit tricky using read_sql_query since the quotes are not handled correctly. Using the "?" is much clearer than passing %s in pymmsql which I believe when used in combination with read_sql_query can make passing strings as parameters tricky since it doesnt handle quotes. Any ideas for workaround there?

Comment: My workaround (and tip) is I never attempt to pass parameters in the way outlined. Note also that very soon there comes a point when it's much preferable to use a stored procedure and then call a simple EXEC and pass in your parameters. See update for how i would do inline sql statements, the technique easily adapted for a stored procedure call if that option is available to you.

Comment: It is not really advised to use python's string formatting, but you should rather use the DBAPI's parameter substitution (so using the `?` in this case). But @Bee, what problems with quotes when passing strings as parameters did you encounter? Can you give an example or point to somewhere it is described?

Comment: Thanks Joris. I am open to the recommendation but was just wondering why the advice against string formatting. Is it security, flexibility, maintainability or other?