# passing param to airflow get_pandas_df and comparing to datetime2

Tags: python, sql-server, format, airflow

Here is the code:

```
#run cassandra query to get date value 
result = session.execute('select max(process_date) as process_date_max from keyspace1.job_run ')
for row in result:
date_last_run = row.process_date_max
date_last_run = str(date_last_run)
sql = """
      select * from table where modifieddate > {last_run}
      """.format(last_run=date_last_run))
df = mssql.get_pandas_df(sql)
```

I get error: cannot compare value of datetime2 with int.  Please help here as i didn't find any solution on internet so far.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. Looks like you're injecting, not parametrising, the value, and as a result it's injecting a value like `2021-08-03`, which would be resolved as the `int` `2010`, or perhaps a value like `'03/08/2021`, which would resolve to the `int` `0`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, you are right . But how do i correct this as i have tried many other options also.

Comment: You need to parametrise your query. I'm not familiar with pandas, but these look promising: [Passing query parameters in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640004/passing-query-parameters-in-pandas), [How can I use multiple parameters using pandas pd.read_sql_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180884/how-can-i-use-multiple-parameters-using-pandas-pd-read-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

The solution in very simple you just need to put the **'**  before and after the {last_run} and your code will work

See the below example

```
result = session.execute('select max(process_date) as process_date_max from keyspace1.job_run ')
for row in result:
date_last_run = row.process_date_max
date_last_run = str(date_last_run)
sql = """
      select * from table where modifieddate > '{last_run}'
      """.format(last_run=date_last_run))
df = mssql.get_pandas_df(sql)
```

Method2:

```
sql = f" select * from table where modifieddate > '{last_run}'"
```

Comment: This is not safe from SQL injection attacks afaik.